# Toggle siblings with jquery

Tags: jquery, toggle, accordion, siblings

I have problems with toggle() in jquery. See http://jsfiddle.net/rch7L/. When clicking a level-1 header it does exactly what it should, but when clicking a level-2 header it opens all level-3 row and not just the level-3 rows under the level-2 header.

```
$('tr.level-2, tr.level-3').css("display", "none");

$("tr.level-1").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('tr.level-2').toggle();
});

$("tr.level-2").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('tr.level-3').toggle();
});
```

I've tried using siblings(), but it does not what I want when clicking level-2 headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [`.nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) method

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rch7L/2/)**</kbd>

```
$("tr.level-2").click(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.level-2').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Love these little jQuery uncommonly known about functions.

Comment: @ChrisDixon yeh, nice little Method :)

Comment: Lovely. If I open level 3 rows and I click level 1, only the level 2 headers will collapse and level 3 will still be visible. I guess `siblings().toggle()` is also the wrong way to do it in the other function?